# Getting info from a link

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, parameters

I have a table setup like

```
ID   Name   Gender
1    John     M
2    Jane     F
```

Where the IDs are hyperlinks taking me to a servlet. I want to know was the number of the link the user clicked to get to the servlet, any idea how to achieve that? I tried putting a name inside the  tag and then using request.getParameter("name") that but it always returns a null. The table is on a .jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

`getParameter("x")` works if the hyperlink clicked had a parameter called `x`, like

```
<a href="..../target.html?x=3">
```

for row three.

Comment: That worked but can I implement that in a dynamic way? I'm using a for loop to print objects from an arraylist and if possible, I would like to avoid having to put x=1, x=2... on every row.

Comment: At your current skill level I think you should put x=1 etc on every row.